# C# System.Net WebClient.DownloadData - Error retrieving proper data

Tags: c#, download, byte

Perhaps the main issue is where I am uploading to - I am currently using [MediaFire](http://www.mediafire.com/) to upload my files. I have tested with downloading files of both ".exe" as well as ".png" formats; neither seem to work for me though.

**The issue that is constantly occurring for me:**

When I attempt to download a file, (I will put the URL's of the two files at the end of my question), the amount of data retrieved is either far greater - or far less than the actual size of the file. For example, I uploaded a blank VB6 executable file which is 16kb. The downloaded file comes out to be nearly 60 kilobytes!

**Some things to note:**

1) Both files download with no problems through Chrome (and I'm assuming other browsers as well).

2) I have tried multiple methods of retrieving the data from the downloaded file (same result).

**My Code:**

```
    // Create a new instance of the System.Net 'WebClient'
    System.Net.WebClient client = new System.Net.WebClient();

    // Download URL

    // PNG File
    string url = @"http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=a16mo8gm03fv1d9&thumb=4";

    // EXE File (blank VB6 exe file @ 16kb)
    //  string url = @"http://www.mediafire.com/download.php?nn1cupi7j5ia7cb";

    // Destination
    string savePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop) + @"\Test.png";

    byte[] result = client.DownloadData(url);

    MessageBox.Show(result.Length.ToString());   // Returns 57,000 something (over 3x larger than my EXE file!).

    // Write downloaded data to desired destination
    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(savePath, result);
```

Comment: What are the extra bytes?  Is it coming back as binary data or html?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would be able to determine if this data is coming back as "html data" or not ... but when I write the file to my HD, the file reads "57kb" or however much it is and will not execute properly.

Comment: try opening the file with notepad and see what it looks like.  :-)

Comment: @agent-j it's downloading the HTML !! What should I do to fix this?

Comment: There could be a session (a http cookie header) that you need.  Is it a site that makes you log in?  Take a look at the html.  Does the html tell the browser to download from some other url?

Comment: @agent-j There was no download link in the HTML. Are there any websites you recommend for uploading files that I should try out?

Comment: The URLs in your code don't point to the actual files, but to HTML pages that contain links to the actual files. Unfortunately, the links seem to be fetched using AJAX, so you would have to simulate that if you wanted to actually download the files.